# Issue with inserting temp table to recursive query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I have the following query.

```
DECLARE @PartNo Char(22)
DECLARE @PartIssue AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @Level AS INT
DECLARE @PartType AS CHAR(12)
DECLARE @TempLeadTime AS FLOAT
DECLARE @CumLeadTime AS FLOAT 
DECLARE @bomlforcursor  AS FLOAT
DECLARE @ldtimeforcursor AS FLOAT
DECLARE @temp_level as float
DECLARE @BomParent as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ldt as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TestCursor as CURSOR

SELECT @PartIssue = drawissno, @PartNo = partnum, @Level=1, @PartType = sm FROM partmaster  where partnum = 'AE40-0287810'

WITH Hierarchyct(BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty) AS
      (SELECT     @Level AS BOMLevel,
                        @PartNo AS bomchild, 
                        @PartType as parttype,
                        cast('' AS CHAR(22)) AS bomparent,  
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = @PartNo) AS ldtime,
                        @PartIssue as childissue, 
                        eccbom AS bmethod, 
                        eccroute as rmethod,
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS requiredqty
                        --@CumLeadTime AS cumleadtime
      FROM eccissue 
      WHERE eccpart = @PartNo AND eccissueno = @PartIssue 

      UNION ALL
      SELECT            (hierarchyct.BOMLevel + 1) AS BOMLevel,
                        bom.bomchild, 
                        (SELECT sm from partmaster where partnum = bom.bomchild) as parttype,
                        bom.bomparent, 
                        bom.bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) as ldtime,
                        --(CASE WHEN (stock.stleadtim = 0 AND parttype = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (bom.bomqty*routing.runtim) ELSE (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) END) AS ldtime,
                        (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AS childissue,
                        bom.baltmethod AS bmethod,    
                        (SELECT eccroute FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccissueno = (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AND eccissue.eccpart = bom.bomchild ) as rmethod,
                        (bom.bomqty * hierarchyct.requiredqty) AS requiredqty
                       -- @CumLeadTime + leadtime as cumleadtime
      FROM bom  INNER JOIN hierarchyct ON bom.bomparent = hierarchyct.bmchild 


      WHERE bom.baltmethod =(SELECT eccbom FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccpart = hierarchyct.bmchild AND eccissue.eccissueno = hierarchyct.childissue )
      )


SELECT * 
FROM
(     
SELECT      hierarchyct.*,
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.bmqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtime, --, SUM(1) as cumldtime
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.requiredqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtimeforRQ

--, SUM(1) as cumldtime
FROM  hierarchyct left outer join routing on part = bmchild and raltmethod = rmethod left outer join stock on stocknum = bmchild  left outer join partmaster on partnum = Hierarchyct.bmchild 
GROUP BY BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty, stleadtim, sm, part
--Where leadtime =0Mr1990
) as temp
```

This works fine, But when I try to get the final result into a temp table (I need this to run a cursor) using this modified query:

```
DECLARE @PartNo Char(22)
DECLARE @PartIssue AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @Level AS INT
DECLARE @PartType AS CHAR(12)
DECLARE @TempLeadTime AS FLOAT
DECLARE @CumLeadTime AS FLOAT 
DECLARE @bomlforcursor  AS FLOAT
DECLARE @ldtimeforcursor AS FLOAT
DECLARE @temp_level as float
DECLARE @BomParent as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ldt as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TestCursor as CURSOR
CREATE TABLE #CumLeadTimRep (BOMLevel INT, bmchild NVARCHAR(50), parttype NVARCHAR(50), bomparent NVARCHAR(50), bmqty INT, leadtime INT, childissue NVARCHAR(50), bmethod INT, method INT, requiredqty INT, ldtime INT, ldtimeforRQ INT)
SELECT @PartIssue = drawissno, @PartNo = partnum, @Level=1, @PartType = sm FROM partmaster  where partnum = 'AE40-0287810'

WITH Hierarchyct(BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty) AS
      (SELECT     @Level AS BOMLevel,
                        @PartNo AS bomchild, 
                        @PartType as parttype,
                        cast('' AS CHAR(22)) AS bomparent,  
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = @PartNo) AS ldtime,
                        @PartIssue as childissue, 
                        eccbom AS bmethod, 
                        eccroute as rmethod,
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS requiredqty
                        --@CumLeadTime AS cumleadtime
      FROM eccissue 
      WHERE eccpart = @PartNo AND eccissueno = @PartIssue 

      UNION ALL
      SELECT            (hierarchyct.BOMLevel + 1) AS BOMLevel,
                        bom.bomchild, 
                        (SELECT sm from partmaster where partnum = bom.bomchild) as parttype,
                        bom.bomparent, 
                        bom.bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) as ldtime,
                        --(CASE WHEN (stock.stleadtim = 0 AND parttype = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (bom.bomqty*routing.runtim) ELSE (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) END) AS ldtime,
                        (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AS childissue,
                        bom.baltmethod AS bmethod,    
                        (SELECT eccroute FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccissueno = (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AND eccissue.eccpart = bom.bomchild ) as rmethod,
                        (bom.bomqty * hierarchyct.requiredqty) AS requiredqty
                       -- @CumLeadTime + leadtime as cumleadtime
      FROM bom  INNER JOIN hierarchyct ON bom.bomparent = hierarchyct.bmchild 


      WHERE bom.baltmethod =(SELECT eccbom FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccpart = hierarchyct.bmchild AND eccissue.eccissueno = hierarchyct.childissue )
      )


SELECT * INTO #CumLeadTimRep()
FROM
(     
SELECT      hierarchyct.*,
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.bmqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtime, --, SUM(1) as cumldtime
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.requiredqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtimeforRQ

--, SUM(1) as cumldtime
FROM  hierarchyct left outer join routing on part = bmchild and raltmethod = rmethod left outer join stock on stocknum = bmchild  left outer join partmaster on partnum = Hierarchyct.bmchild 
GROUP BY BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty, stleadtim, sm, part
--Where leadtime =0Mr1990
) as temp

SELECT * FROM #CumLeadTimRep
```

I get the following errors.

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>   There is already an object named '#CumLeadTimRep' in the database.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Tried a lot but it doesn't get fixed. What could be the issue?

Comment: Where are error messages?

Comment: added them, sorry I forgot that.

Comment: The error seems fairly self explanatory.... You are trying to create a table that already exists. To correct this before you create the table with  `SELECT * INTO #CumLeadTimRep`, simply add a check to see if the table already exists before you try to create it -- `IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#CumLeadTimRep', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CumLeadTimRep;`

Comment: `SELECT * INTO #CumLeadTimRep` creates the table. If it already exists it will throw an error. Instead create the table first once, then use `INSERT INTO #CumLeadTimRep (column1,column2....) SELECT .....`

Comment: Just Create an Temp table Drop Syntax

Comment: Does this mean that , to create a temp table i don't need to have a create table statement?

Comment: The easiest way to fix this issue is to declare either a table variable or a temp table and instead insert into it, rather than creating it on the fly.

Comment: "Does this mean that , to create a temp table i don't need to have a create table statement". This is your problem. You _dont_ have a create table statement. You have a `SELECT INTO` which tries to create it every time. The second time around it **already** exists. If you had _one_ create table at the top (or even better a DECLARE Table variable) and use `INSERT SELECT` it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. issues was with trying to create a table that already existed. The correct syntax is as belows:

```
DECLARE @PartNo Char(22)
DECLARE @PartIssue AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @Level AS INT
DECLARE @PartType AS CHAR(12)
DECLARE @TempLeadTime AS FLOAT
DECLARE @CumLeadTime AS FLOAT 
DECLARE @bomlforcursor  AS FLOAT
DECLARE @ldtimeforcursor AS FLOAT
DECLARE @temp_level as float
DECLARE @BomParent as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ldt as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TestCursor as CURSOR
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#CumLeadTimRep') IS NOT NULL 
begin
DROP TABLE #CumLeadTimRep
end
--CREATE TABLE #CumLeadTimRep (BOMLevel INT, bmchild NVARCHAR(50), parttype NVARCHAR(50), bomparent NVARCHAR(50), bmqty INT, leadtime INT, childissue NVARCHAR(50), bmethod INT, method INT, requiredqty INT, ldtime INT, ldtimeforRQ INT)
SELECT @PartIssue = drawissno, @PartNo = partnum, @Level=1, @PartType = sm FROM partmaster  where partnum = 'AE40-0287810'
WITH Hierarchyct(BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty) AS
      (SELECT     @Level AS BOMLevel,
                        @PartNo AS bomchild, 
                        @PartType as parttype,
                        cast('' AS CHAR(22)) AS bomparent,  
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = @PartNo) AS ldtime,
                        @PartIssue as childissue, 
                        eccbom AS bmethod, 
                        eccroute as rmethod,
                        cast(1.0 AS FLOAT) AS requiredqty
                        --@CumLeadTime AS cumleadtime
      FROM eccissue 
      WHERE eccpart = @PartNo AND eccissueno = @PartIssue 

      UNION ALL
      SELECT            (hierarchyct.BOMLevel + 1) AS BOMLevel,
                        bom.bomchild, 
                        (SELECT sm from partmaster where partnum = bom.bomchild) as parttype,
                        bom.bomparent, 
                        bom.bomqty, 
                        (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) as ldtime,
                        --(CASE WHEN (stock.stleadtim = 0 AND parttype = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (bom.bomqty*routing.runtim) ELSE (SELECT stleadtim FROM stock WHERE stocknum = bom.bomchild) END) AS ldtime,
                        (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AS childissue,
                        bom.baltmethod AS bmethod,    
                        (SELECT eccroute FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccissueno = (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(bom.bomissue)) = 'CURR' THEN (SELECT drawissno FROM PartMaster WHERE PartNum = bom.bomchild) ELSE bom.bomissue END) AND eccissue.eccpart = bom.bomchild ) as rmethod,
                        (bom.bomqty * hierarchyct.requiredqty) AS requiredqty
                       -- @CumLeadTime + leadtime as cumleadtime
      FROM bom  INNER JOIN hierarchyct ON bom.bomparent = hierarchyct.bmchild 


      WHERE bom.baltmethod =(SELECT eccbom FROM eccissue WHERE eccissue.eccpart = hierarchyct.bmchild AND eccissue.eccissueno = hierarchyct.childissue )
      )

SELECT * INTO #CumLeadTimRep
FROM
(     
SELECT      hierarchyct.*,
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.bmqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtime, --, SUM(1) as cumldtime
CASE WHEN (stleadtim = 0 AND partmaster.sm = 'MANUFACTURED') THEN (Hierarchyct.requiredqty*sum(routing.runtim)) ELSE stleadtim  END AS ldtimeforRQ
--, SUM(1) as cumldtime
FROM  hierarchyct left outer join routing on part = bmchild and raltmethod = rmethod left outer join stock on stocknum = bmchild  left outer join partmaster on partnum = Hierarchyct.bmchild 
GROUP BY BOMLevel,bmchild, parttype, bomparent, bmqty, leadtime, childissue,bmethod,rmethod, requiredqty, stleadtim, sm, part
--Where leadtime =0Mr1990
) as temp
SELECT * FROM #CumLeadTimRep
```